# vscode with neovim doesn't save file on :w command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, neovim

I'm using Ubuntu Xenial (yes I know it's out of date, I'm going to upgrade it soon), neovim 0.6.0 (which apt tells me is the latest version), and vscode 1.60.1. Until recently could save files with the :w command, but all of a sudden when I use that command nothing happens. It probably happened when my version of vscode was updated, but I'm not sure. Is there a setting somewhere that controls this, or could something have overridden it? Googling it shows fairly old results, and since it was working a few weeks ago I'm not sure how helpful those ones are.

Ctrl + s works but I'm so used to using :w that I do it automatically and it takes me time to remember to do it the other way. Also, since :w works in all other vims that I use, I'd like to get vscode working the same way again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this problem too and I found that the solution is to **use neovim stable, not the prerelease 0.6.x version.** Now all the editor commands work fine.

I found this solution via this GitHub issues link: https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim/issues/736

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I hadn't even realized that I had the unstable version, I probably just followed instructions to install it without thinking about it.

Comment: Alternately, if you want to stay 0.6.x version: `:wa` is worked for me even `:w` is not working